# Facebook Instant Games: Stuck at loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-instant-games

We're trying to put our HTML5 game on Phaser into Instant Games. The game loads when opening from PC browser by `https://www.facebook.com/instantgames/...` link. But whrn trying to pone the game from an Android FB app, the loading progress starts but gets stuck at some random figure at about 70-90%.

Have anyone dealt with something like this? Or maybe you know a way to debug it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the progress gets stuck simply because there's some exception behind it. It may be a server responding with 500 or it may be a JS exception. To find out the exception that was behind the problem we just opened the game at `m.facebook.com` with DevTools.